# Vue mounted called twice

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I have a problem with the child components of a vue-router route because when I navigate to one of them, the component is loaded twice and therefore the ajax requests that I have within said component are executed twice.  Why is that happening?

Source code:

VerticalTabs.html Component:

```
<div>
    <h3 class="ml-4 mt-2 mb-2 primary--text flex">MENU</h3>
    <v-tabs vertical height="100%" style="overflow: auto;">
        <v-tab v-for="(tab, index) in tabs" :key="index" :to="tab.path" exact>
            <p class="ma-0 flex text-left">
                {{ tab.name }}
            </p>
        </v-tab>
        <v-tab-item v-for="(tab, index) of tabs" :key="index" :value="tab.path">
            <router-view :key="index"></router-view>
        </v-tab-item>
    </v-tabs>
</div>
```

VerticalTabs.js Component:

```
import VueTypes from "vue-types";
export default {
  name: 'VerticalTabs',
  props: {
    tabs: VueTypes.arrayOf(
      VueTypes.shape({
        name: VueTypes.string.isRequired,
        path: VueTypes.string.isRequired
      })
    ).isRequired
  }
};
```

routes.js

```
...other routes
{
     path: "/",
     name: "athletes_main",
     component: MainAthlete,
     children: [
          {
               path: "/athletes",
               name: "athletes",
               component: Athletes
          },
          {
               path: "/athletes/requests",
               name: "athletes_requests",
               component: AthleteRequests
          }
    ]
}
```

MainAthlete.js Component file:

```
import { VerticalTabs } from "@/components";

export default {
  name: 'MainAthlete',
  components: {VerticalTabs},
  data () {
    return {
      tabs: [
        {
          name: "ATHLETES",
          path: "/athletes"
        },
        {
          name: "ATHLETES REQUESTS",
          path: "/athletes/requests"
        },
      ]
    }
  },
}
```

MainAthletes.html

```
<section class="main_athletes">
  <VerticalTabs :tabs="tabs" />
</section>
```

AthleteRequests.js

```
...
mounted(){
     //Ajax request...
}
```

Thank you! :D

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? I am having the same issue. I am skeptical of Kapcash's response since you are following the Vuetify example, as am I.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have multiple `<router-view>` component in your page!

This `vue-router` component is meant to indicate where your current page component should be renderer. So if you're on the page "/athletes/requests", it will renderer your `AthleteRequests` twice!

So just get rid of your `v-for` loop around your `router-view` component, so that you have only one.

Also, you could register the "/athletes/requests" route as a child route of "/athletes". See the [vue-router documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html) about nested routes.